# What is more efficient or recommended for reading output of a command into variables in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, process-substitution, here-string

If you want to read the single line output of a system command into Bash shell variables, you have at least two options, as in the examples below:

1. `IFS=: read user x1 uid gid x2 home shell <<<$(grep :root: /etc/passwd | head -n1)`

and

2. `IFS=: read user x1 uid gid x2 home shell < <(grep :root: /etc/passwd | head -n1)`

Is there any difference between these two? What is more efficient or recommended?

---

Please note that, reading the `/etc/passwd` file is just for making an example. The focus of my question is on *here strings* vs. *process substitution*.

Comment: Instead of grepping the password file you might want to use ˋgetent passwd rootˋ instead. It works for multiple user sources and might use internal,cache and lookup index.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First note that using `read` without `-r` is to process input where `\` is used to escape the field or line delimiters which is not the case of `/etc/passwd`. It's very rare that you would want to use `read` without `-r`.

Now as to those two forms, a note that neither are standard `sh` syntax. `<<<` is from `zsh` in 1991. `<(...)` is from `ksh` circa 1985 though `ksh` initially didn't support redirecting from/to it.

`$(...)` is also from ksh, but has been standardised by POSIX (as it replaces the ill-designed `` `...` `` from the Bourne shell), so is portable across `sh` implementations these days.

`$(code)` interprets the code in a subshell with the output redirected to a pipe while the parent at the same time, reads that output from the other end of the pipe and stores it in memory. Then once that command finishes, that output, stripped of the trailing newline characters (and with the NUL characters removed in `bash`) makes up the expansion of `$(...)`.

If that `$(...)` is not quoted and is in list context, it is subject  to split+glob (split only in zsh). After `<<<`, it's not a list context, but still [older versions of `bash` would still do the split part (not glob) and then join the parts with spaces](/a/397208). So if using `bash`, you'd likely want to also quote `$(...)` when used as target of `<<<`.

`cmd <<< word` in zsh and older versions of bash causes the shell to store `word` followed by a newline character into a temporary file, which is then made the stdin of the process that will execute `cmd`, and that tempfile deleted before `cmd` is executed. That's the same as happens with `<< EOF` from the Bourne shell from the 70s. Effectively, it is exactly the same as:

```
cmd << EOF
word
EOF
```

In 5.1, bash switched from using a temporary file to using a pipe as long as the word can fit whole in the pipe buffer (and falls back to using a tempfile if not to avoid deadlocks) and makes `cmd`'s stdin the reading end of the pipe which the shell has seeded beforehand with the `word`.

So `cmd1 <<< "$(cmd2)"` involves one or two pipes, store the whole output of `cmd2` in memory, storing it again in either another pipe or a tempfile and mangles the NULs and newlines.

`cmd1 < <(cmd2)` is functionality equivalent to `cmd2 | cmd1`. `cmd2`'s output is connected to the writing end of a pipe. Then `<(...)` expands to a path that identifies the other end, `< that-path` gets you a file descriptor to that other end. So `cmd2` talks directly to `cmd1` without the shell doing anything with the data.

You see this kind of construct in the `bash` shell specifically because in `bash`, contrary to AT&T ksh or zsh, in:

```
cmd2 | cmd1
```

`cmd1` is run in a subshell¹, so if `cmd1` is `read` for instance, `read` will only populate variables of that subshell.

So here, you would want:

```
IFS=: read -r user x1 uid gid x2 home shell rest_if_any_ignored < <(
  grep :root: /etc/passwd)
```

The `head` is superfluous as with `-r`, `read` will only read one line anyway². I've added a `rest_if_any_ignored` for future proofing in case in the future a new field is added to `/etc/passwd`, causing `$shell` to contain `/bin/sh:that-field` otherwise.

Portably (in `sh`), you can't do:

```
grep :root: /etc/passwd |
  IFS=: read -r user x1 uid gid x2 home shell rest_if_any_ignored
```

as POSIX leaves it unspecified whether `read` runs in a subshell (like in `bash`/`dash`...) or not (like `zsh`/`ksh`).

You can however do:

```
IFS=: read -r user x1 uid gid x2 home shell rest_if_any_ignored << EOF
$(grep :root: /etc/passwd | head -n1)
EOF
```

(here restoring the `head` to avoid the whole of `grep`'s output to be stored in memory and in the tempfile/pipe).

Which is standard even if not as efficient (though as indicated by @muru, the difference for such a small input is likely negligible compared to the cost of running an external utility in a forked process).

Performance, if that mattered here, could  be improved by using builtin features of the shell to do `grep`'s job. However, especially in `bash`, you'd only do that for very small input as a shell is not designed for this kind of task and is going to be a lot worse at it than `grep`.

```
while
  IFS=: read <&3 -r user x1 uid gid name home shell rest_if_any_ignored
do
  if [ "$name" = root ]; then
    do-something-with "$user" "$home"...
    break
  fi
done 3< /etc/passwd
```

---

<sup>¹ except when the `lastpipe` option in `bash` is set and the shell is non-interactive like in scripts</sup>

<sup>² see also the `-m1` or `--max-count=1` option of the GNU implementation of `grep` which would tell `grep` itself to stop searching after the first match. Or the portable equivalent: `sed '/:root:/!d;q'`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the "historical" explanation. I am interested only in Bash 5.1 or above though. In my case, Bash seems to behave the same in `cmd1 <<<$(cmd2)` and `cmd1 <<<"$(cmd2)"`. Also the `rest_if_any_ignored` tip was something that I already know, but ignored for simplicity. The fact that `read` will read only one line and the `-r` switch of it  which is almost always necessary was a useful extra tip. I will accept this answer instead of @muru's (sorry @muru) because, ***although it comes after @muru's***, it is somehow more detailed.

Comment: Can you comment on the usage of file descriptor 3 in the last example?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, that's to avoid clobering 0, 1, 2 which are stdin/stdout/stderr and that commands in the loop may want to access. See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) (thanks for edit btw).

Answer (score 6):

In [herestrings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), bash reads in the entire output of the command substitution (`$(grep :root: /etc/passwd | head -n1)`) to create the contents of the herestring, and then you tell it to read it again with `read`.

On the other hand, with [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), bash sets up a pipe, and then you read in the output *once*.

---

You're running bash (and two other external commands) to read in one line. At that point, efficiency has long since been defenestrated.

---

While we're at it, [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control) has a `-m` option:

> `-m` *num*
> `--max-count`=*num*
>
> Stop after the first *num* selected lines.

Comment: So, "process substitution" may be the (slightly) preferred method, if I understand correctly. Thanks also for the extra `grep` tip! :)