# How can I concat results in the here document?

Tags: bash, find, cat, here-document, here-string

I have this script:

```
while read $item;
do
    # Some bash logic here
done <<< "$({ cat /path/to/some/file; echo; })"
```

Now I want to also use `find` to find the name of some directories, and pass that alongside the `cat` to the `while` loop.

In other words, I want to:

- `cat` a file
- `find` some directories
- Concatenate the results
- Feed them as here-document to the `while` loop

I'm stuck at this point.

I though of duplicating the `while` logic, which is not a good method. I also thought of reusing the logic inside the `while` loop using functions.

However, concatenating stuff in here-document might seem to be the correct way to do it.

Comment: Putting the clunkiness and limitations of `<<< "$(…)"` aside, a note: you already concatenate the output of `cat` and the output of `echo`. Sole `echo` prints a newline and it's futile here because `$()` removes all trailing newlines (and then `<<<` adds exactly one). My point is you already concatenate the results of two commands. :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I guess that's the result of copy/pasting codes without truly understanding them. Somewhere I got that code and it worked. :D

Comment: Getting the expected output from some specific set of sample input from any code doesn't mean that code "works", it just means it didn't fail for that test case. Don't use code you don't understand as there'll probably be cases not present in whatever sample data you tested with that come back to bite you later when run on your (or your customers'!) real data.

Answer (score 5):

Actually `<<< "$({ cat /path/to/some/file; echo; })"` is a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) containing a quoted [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) rather than a here-document. As [Kamil Maciorowski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108618/kamil-maciorowski) has [already pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736691/how-can-i-concat-results-in-the-here-document/736741#comment1398987_736691), you already know how to concatenate the results of the two commands `cat /path/to/some/file` and `echo` inside the command substitution, and you could do the same with `cat` and `find`:

```
... <<< "$(cat /path/to/some/file; find . -name '*foo*')"
```

I omitted the inner `{ ... }` since the commands are already grouped by `$( ... )`.

However it would be more natural IMHO to use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#index-process-substitution) to concatenate the outputs. To see how that works, start from simple input redirection

```
while IFS= read -r item
do
    # Some bash logic here
done < /path/to/some/file
```

which redirects the contents of the file to the loop via stdin; then

```
while IFS= read -r item
do
    # Some bash logic here
done < <(cat /path/to/some/file)
```

which converts the output of `cat /path/to/some/file` to a pseudo-file that you can redirect in the same way. Now it's a simple matter to add another stdout-generating command to the process list:

```
while IFS= read -r item
do
    # Some bash logic here
done < <(cat /path/to/some/file; find . -name '*foo*')
```

See for example

- [What is more efficient or recommended for reading output of a command into variables in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654067/what-is-more-efficient-or-recommended-for-reading-output-of-a-command-into-varia)
- [Why does a Bash 'while' read loop with a command substitution herestring not read the entire input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575043/why-does-a-bash-while-read-loop-with-a-command-substitution-herestring-not-rea)

Note that in all cases, the syntax is `read item` not `read $item`.

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching me. May I ask why should I not use `here-string`?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I've updated the answer with additional explanation and references